# d3 pie labels aren't in right place, centroids are way off for some reason

Tags: d3.js

I'm building a d3 pie chart with labels on the centroids just like so many examples. I've checked my code against many of those examples but can't figure out where or how my centroids are being calculated. The labels appear to be arranged around the origin of the svg and not the center of the chart like I'd expect. I feel like there's a grouping issue since the text is added but it's not grouped with the arc. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to fix it.

```
var arcs = svg.datum(domain)
            .selectAll('path')
            .data(pie);

arcs.enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('fill', function(d, i){
        return color[i];
    })
    .attr('d', arc)
    .each(function(d) { 
            this._current = d; 
    }) // store the initial angles
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + outerRadius + ", " + outerRadius + ')');

arcs.enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
    console.log(arc.centroid(d));
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d,i) { 
        return data[i].playerName+": "+data[i].playerScore;
    });
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johnlayne/6pk2zjtb/) with the complete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also move the text over to adjust for the radius of the chart:

```
arcs.enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
        console.log(arc.centroid(d));
                return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")translate(" + outerRadius + ", " + outerRadius + ")";
        })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d,i) { 
            return data[i].playerName+": "+data[i].playerScore;
    });
```

This will shift everything over to match the locations of the arcs' centroids.